# Authenticate a webservice with active directory users in ios application?

Tags: ios, json, web-services, active-directory

I am developing a client application in ios. In this application i need to get service data from a web service, this service will only accessable for active directory users but not for anonymous users.How can i access and fetch data from that web service using active directory users credentials.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to pass user credentials while hitting web services.

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ur URL"]];
        NSString *userPasswordString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",username,password];
        NSData * userPasswordData = [userPasswordString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *base64EncodedCredential = [userPasswordData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
        NSString *authString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", base64EncodedCredential];

        NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSString *msgLength =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[poststr length]];

        [req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [req addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.hello.com"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
        [req addValue:authString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
        [req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [req setHTTPBody: [poststr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
         {
            // NSError *error1;


         }];
```

Comment: Hi Singapore thanks for quick reply, in my application am fetching the service data using MKNetworkKit. So is there any solution for my question using mknetwork.